# Can't save user to mongodb in Spring 5 WebFlux

Tags: java, mongodb, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I try to save User to Mongo database in reactive style with Spring WebFlux, but data isn't saved, so I have Java 8, Spring 5 and mongodb.

This is my config:

My entity:

```
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

My repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String> {
}
```

My web config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction userRoutes() {
        return route(POST("/admin/users").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)),
                        request -> {
                            Mono<User> user = request.bodyToMono(User.class);
                            Mono<User> userMono = user.doOnNext(userRepository::save)
                            return ServerResponse.().body(userMono, User.class);
                        });
    }
}
```

May be I have to manual execute subscribe after save to repository, but I havn't found such info in spring reference?

**UPD:**
But if I extract from request User and pass it to userRepository and return result I have got a successful result to save data to mongo. But I am not sure that it is a good approach:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction userRoutes() {
    return route(POST("/admin/users").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)),
                    request -> {
                        User user = request.bodyToMono(User.class).block();
                        Mono<User> userMono = userRepository.save(user);
                        return ServerResponse.ok().body(userMono, User.class);
                    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed doOnNext to flatMap and it works, so it seems to me this is due to the fact that "Transform the item emitted by this Mono asynchronously, returning the value emitted by another Mono" and doOnNext - "Add behavior triggered when the Mono emits a data successfully" and userRepository.save(...) method return Mono that doOnNext add behavious to old Mono and return it(I am loosing response from save method) and flatMap return new Mono which got from save method:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction userRoutes() {
    return route(POST("/admin/users").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)),
                    request -> {
                        Mono<User> user = request.bodyToMono(User.class);
                            Mono<User> userMono = user.flatMap(userRepository::save);
                            return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(userMono, User.class);
                    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. The _doOn_... methods are usually used for logging purposes. The _flatMap_ is the natural operator for your use case.